# gc/c++ omit main from compilation, provide main in separate file

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'd like to do a compilation of two files which contain main methods by excluding or omitting the main method defined in one.

To give some background:

I'm trying to automate testing student-submitted code against a main method I provide.

My trouble is that the student code *also* included a main method. I'm wondering how I can compile (using g++) the file while excluding main. I'd just like to get the object code for the methods they define and link that with my new main method.

I'd rather find an automated way to do this rather than be forced to edit by hand 100s of submissions to remove / replace the main method.

Thanks

Comment: Teach the students how to build programs using multiple source or object files? Then provide a a precompiled object file containing your own `main` function to the students and tell them to not write their own?

Comment: You might add flag `-Dmain=main2` for their files.

Comment: Yes after this first example they will be putting their methods in separate files. This was just to keep it simple for now.

Thanks Jarod42, looks like that will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might add flag `-Dmain=main2` for their files.

That mainly add `#define main main2` which will substitute their main by a regular method.

Notice though that as `main` is a special method, especially, we can omit final `return 0;`, you should adapt warning configuration to not reject code with `main2` without `return` (which fortunately would just be a warning and not an error).